# Url redirects in Sitecore/uCommerce

Tags: asp.net, redirect, sitecore, sitecore7, umbraco-ucommerce

I am developing an e-Commerce solution using Sitecore and uCommerce. I have found 2 modules for Sitecore to do URL redirecting.

- https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Redirect_Manager.aspx
- https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/301_Redirect_module.aspx

Both seem to satisfy the old url -> new url manual process of redirecting, although a little removed from the actual content. Are there any better solutions/packages? I am thinking more like how Umbraco's 301 Url Tracker works (http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker). It is more content item specific and tracks changes in the page title and therefore Url to create a redirect for you.

Also does anyone know if uCommerce tracks changes in the product name/sku that might affect the url requiring a 301 to the updated location?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't track them no, that's something you'd have to code up yourself. You'd be best to hook into the SaveProduct pipeline I think and update another table.

HTH